# Comparing two Arraylists in android

Tags: android, arraylist, sqlite, compare

i have two arraylists named **arraylist1** and **arraaylist2**.

```
Arraylist1 having fileds instock,Productcode,productname,batchnNo,saledQty,discount and amount, Which stores values from database table named ProductDetails.

Arraylist2 having fields Productcode,minQuantity,maxQuantity,discount,discountType, which stores values from different table  named DiscountDetails.
```

we need to **compare**  arraylist1 and arraylist2 based on the **productcode** . if the productcode is same then ***i need to check the saledQty***  of perticular productcode
from arraylist1 and we need to check weather it will fall in the range between minQuantity and maxQuantity of arraylist2.**(minQty<=saledQty<=maxQty**)

if it fall in between range of minQuantity and maxQuantity we need to get **discount** from **arraylist2** for that perticular productCode and we need to show it in the position of **discount** column of that perticular code in **arraylist1**.

Can any One help me on this.. thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Sorry.Actually i am very new to java. i don't know how to implement this concept. That's why i'm posting this question. please help me

Comment: Quite frankly, this smells of homework. As pointed out in the answer below, it could all be done in SQL, otherwise you need to look at the Android `Cursor` class, perhaps. You really do need to have some code before you can get any concrete help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to solve this at database SQL query side. This can easily be put into sql query.

**EDIT in response to vote down:**

Try this SQL instead of processing two lists. This gives all products with discount codes if `saledqty` is between min and max otherwise gives whatever product.discount is.

```
select p.instock, p.Productcode, p.productname, p.batchnNo, p.saledQty, p.amount, 
        isnull(d.discount, p.discount)
from 
    ProductDetails p
left join 
        DiscountDetails d on p.Productcode = d.Productcode 
        and p.saledQty between d.minQuantity and d.maxQuantity
```

If only interested in products that have valid discount then change `left join` (outer join) to `join` (inner join).